# Visiting Geneva but booked a nearby hotel in France

Tags: schengen, switzerland, eu-citizens, spouses

I am a UK citizen and my husband has applied for Schengen multiple entry visa through the Swiss Embassy. We are flying to and visiting Geneva but I accidentally booked a hotel which is across the French border. Will this be a  problem for my husband, to stay in France instead of in Switzerland?

Comment: France is part of the Schengen zone.

Comment: No reason it should be a problem. A Schengen visa covers both countries and given the geography of the region, there is nothing suspicious or unusual about crossing the border. Furthermore, since you are a British citizen, you are (for the time being) making use of your right to free movement within the EU (which covers Switzerland, at least in this situation). This give you and your husband more extensive rights, the consulate is not supposed to evaluate the purpose or details of the trip at all.

Comment: There might be a problem if an official thinks that you *intentionally misrepresented* facts. Given the family situation, your husband should have gotten a Schengen visa from France just as easily as he got it from Switzerland, so the odds are that there will be no questions. You might want to keep receipts, etc. to show that the main destination of your trip was Switzerland, and that you actually spent lots of time there.

Comment: @Relaxed you might also mention that the husband's visa should be free of charge.

Comment: @o.m., actually, because the couple are traveling under the freedom of movement directive, intentional misrepresentation of facts would not be grounds for denial of the visa or denial of entry.  Even without that, it's probably untrue that the visa should have been handled by France.  If someone is sleeping in a French hotel but spending days in Geneva, then Switzerland remains the main destination, and should be the country handling the visa application.

Comment: @phoog, hence my suggestion to document that Switzerland really was the main destination.

Comment: @o.m. Visiting Geneva and booking an hotel near Geneva is enough. It would be strange to check a Schengen visa in France just because one plan to stay in a hotel in "nowhere", near the border. This would be more suspicious. (France near Geneva is nearly "nowhere" for French standards)

Comment: @Relaxed your comment is very much an answer; add it and I'll upvote.

Comment: If you have already gotten a visa then there is no problem at all. If your applications are still pending, then there is a chance that the Swiss might ask you to apply at France consulate.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for the Schengen Visa Visa from the country where you have the main purpose to travel.

Example:

- You are going to professional a conference in Madrid, Spain for 2 days
- You would like also to spend 4 nights in Lisbon, Portugal on the way back

In this case, the country of the main purpose is Spain, while you will spend less nights. Of course, it is much easier when you will spend more time in the country you applied Visa for.

In your case, the main purpose of travel is to visit Geneva. It does not matter, that you will sleep in France. In case you are asked, just be ready to explain to border officer, that you have booked the hotel in France to save money, while you are going to spend all the time in Geneva. I am sure that you will get entrance stamps without such questions.